# rename multiple labels in sequence with mysql

Tags: java, mysql, jlabel, jtextfield

### Problem

I want to change my Label with database mapel and textfield with database Nilai. i already try many ways but its doesnt work. you guys have any idea ?

### Source

```
try{
    sql2 = "SELECT Mapel, Nilai FROM Nilai where NIM = '" + tf_main.getText() + "'";
    rs3 = stmt.executeQuery(sql2);
    while(rs3.next()){
        siswa asd = new siswa();
        String nilai = rs3.getString("Nilai");
        asd.label_nilai1.setText(rs3.getString("Mapel"));
        asd.tf_nilai1.setText(nilai);

        }
    }
}catch(SQLException se){
    se.printStackTrace();
}catch(Exception aae){
    aae.printStackTrace();
}
```

### Source 2

```
    label_nilai1 = new JLabel(MP1);
    label_nilai2 = new JLabel(MP2);
    label_nilai3 = new JLabel(MP3);
    label_nilai4 = new JLabel(MP4);
    label_nilai5 = new JLabel(MP5);
    tf_nilai1 = new JTextField(15);
    tf_nilai2 = new JTextField(15);
    tf_nilai3 = new JTextField(15);
    tf_nilai4 = new JTextField(15);
    tf_nilai5 = new JTextField(15);
```

### Database

[image]

## Output

[image]